# In Linux ,how to connect two vNIC?

Tags: linux, virtual

here is my question:
I create vlan device eth0.10 and veth-pair(if_in and if_out) on Centos ,how to connetc eth0.10  to if_in ??

ip link add link eth0 name eth0.10 type vlan protocol 802.1Q id 100

ip link add name  if_in type veth peer name if_out

I am not very understanding linux virtual network.Is there any way can solve this problem ?
I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a virtual switch or bridge as described in [this page](http://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=66).

Although the page used network namespace, the basic idea is still adding eth0.10 and if_in into the same vswitch/bridge and let the openvswitch/linux bridge do the work.

one example using linux bridge:

```
# create the switch
BRIDGE=br-test
brctl addbr $BRIDGE
brctl stp   $BRIDGE off
ip link set dev $BRIDGE up
brctl addif br-test eth0.10
brctl addif br-test if_in
```